# Can I run istio without enabling mtls?

Tags: istio

Can we run istio without enabling mtls?

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can have a Kubernetes cluster with Istio installed, without global mutual TLS enabled (e.g use install/kubernetes/istio.yaml as described in installation steps, or set global.mtls.enabled to false using Helm).
https://istio.io/docs/tasks/security/authn-policy/#before-you-begin